# How to test the Youtube Content API without an account with many videos?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I am building an app using the Youtube API V3. I want to test how it works listing many videos, but I do not have an account with such videos. Is there any demo or test account Youtube offers to developers? If not, how could I test an app that expects the user to have more than 1,000 videos.

Comment: you need to be authenticated ?

Comment: Yes, the idea is to list all your own videos, everyone